# Custom DatePicker with just two components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I want to to use custom `datePicker` in my project. In Mode date it shows `Month,Day and Year`, in my case I don't need Year, I just want to display `Month and day`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not provide a way to do this.  If you want to be able to, please [file a report requesting this ability](https://bugreport.apple.com), and it'll hopefully get included in a future release of iOS.

In the meantime, you can make a pretty convincing replica yourself using a `UIPickerView`.

Comment: Thanks alot, I made a pickerView with two components.

Answer (score 2):

Im sorry but following the reference of the PickerView

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDatePickerMode

It says that is not possible to do that, so your only option is to implemente yourself the delegate and the datasource, and create the pickerview with the data you need.

Comment: Yup I know it's not in given modes, therefore I ask for custom, by the way, thanks for the answer.